# Javascript IFs (sonar false positive?)

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I just found one misleading issue in the SonarQube, 
we have code as follows (JS)

```
{…}
function test(searchQuery, role) {

console.log("inputs: " +searchQuery + ", " + role );
    if (!searchQuery && role) {
        console.log("first");
    }
    if (searchQuery && !role) {
        console.log("sec");
    }
    if (searchQuery && role) {
        console.log("3");
    }
    console.log("END");
}
{…}
```

And Sonarqube (6.7.4) marked the last If as issue with comment it should be fixed to avoid being everytime `true`
(in the first IFs there is a return in fact, I modified the code for testing purpose)

With the tested values, output was:

```
inputs: aaa, fff
test.txt.html:14 3
test.txt.html:16 END
test.txt.html:6 inputs: null, fff
test.txt.html:8 first
test.txt.html:16 END
test.txt.html:6 inputs: null, null
test.txt.html:16 END
```

I am not a javascript expert, just found interesting that, does has anyone idea, `if there is any reason why the last if should be everytime true`?
Because I dont think so, reg. testing data.

> If you will place returns into first two IFs to be in place, then the code will continue in two cases:
>   - if both variables are set, or if both are null, but `if (null, null)` should return undefined, not?

Thanks for any clarifications

Comment: Without seeing your actual code it could be that sonarqube is detecting (perhaps erroneously)  that by the time the code gets past your first two IFs the other IF is unnecessary, especially if you are returning.

Comment: Ah, maybe that can be issue, because while code is going through third if, there is a "generic" return, actually with another value then all previous ifs are having, but yes, maybe from the perspective of the scanner it results as this, anyway thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to help you if you were giving the code which is actually analyzed and the precise issue you get in SonarQube. I couldn't reproduce any issue with the code you posted, but I could reproduce one with `return` statements in every `if` block (based on the note at the end of your message).

```
function test(searchQuery, role) {
    if (!searchQuery && role) {
        return;
    }
    if (searchQuery && !role) {
        return;
    }
    if (searchQuery && role) {
        return;
    }
}
```

SonarQube then highlights `role` in the condition of the third `if` statement and raises the following issue: *Refactor this code so that this expression does not always evaluate to true.*

When `searchQuery` is truthy and `role` is falsy, the condition of the second `if` statement is true and the second `return` statement is executed.
That means that `role` can't be falsy when `searchQuery` is truthy in the condition of the third `if` statement. In other words, `role` can be removed from the condition of the third `if` statement without affecting the behavior.

Comment: Hi, Pierre, thanks for the explanation, this is exactly the issue, but if I am correct, then- you will `call function with both of variables set to false` value, then `first if did not match, second not, as well, but also third one will don't match the condition`, not? in this case, code will continue bellow avoiding all conditions of the IF block, if I am correct, or am I miss something?

Comment: SonarQube does not imply that the full condition of the third `if` statement is always true. It's only the `role` subcondition which is redundant here and which can be removed without affecting the behavior: `if (searchQuery) {...}`

Comment: Ah, I think i got it, so technically, its possible only to test the first (searchquery) parameter, because both cases are already tested in the code above. So, as you mentioned, once code got there, it means role is already true.
Thank you for the clarification, have a nice day.